speedup btrfs by storing metadata on ssd
I have a btrfs volume with 8 disks (5 x 8 TB, 3 x 16 TB) in RAID1C3. To speed up some file operations, I've added a 460 GB SSD partition to the volume and intended to store metadata there.
I did btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1c3 /data, which ended up in:
$ btrfs fi us -T /data
Overall:
    Device size:                  85.95TiB
    Device allocated:             23.75TiB
    Device unallocated:           62.21TiB
    Device missing:                  0.00B
    Used:                         23.67TiB
    Free (estimated):             20.75TiB      (min: 20.75TiB)
    Free (statfs, df):            16.20TiB
    Data ratio:                       3.00
    Metadata ratio:                   3.00
    Global reserve:              512.00MiB      (used: 0.00B)
    Multiple profiles:                  no

                  Data    Metadata  System
Id Path           RAID1C3 RAID1C3   RAID1C3  Unallocated
-- -------------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
 1 /dev/sdb             -         -        -     7.28TiB
 2 /dev/sdf             -         -        -     7.28TiB
 3 /dev/sdg             -         -        -     7.28TiB
 4 /dev/sdd             -         -        -     7.28TiB
 5 /dev/sdc             -         -        -     7.28TiB
 6 /dev/sdh       7.82TiB 102.00GiB 32.00MiB     8.46TiB
 7 /dev/sda       7.82TiB 102.00GiB 32.00MiB     8.46TiB
 8 /dev/sde       7.82TiB 102.00GiB 32.00MiB     8.46TiB
 9 /dev/nvme0n1p3       -         -        -   461.61GiB
-- -------------- ------- --------- -------- -----------
   Total          7.82TiB 102.00GiB 32.00MiB    62.21TiB
   Used           7.79TiB  98.64GiB  1.38MiB

So no metadata was stored on ssd (/dev/nvme0n1p3), and also neither metadata nor data was stored on any smaller device than the 3 big ones. Any idea how to leverage SSDs to speedup btrfs volumes?
